# WPF and windows 10, resolution and scale

Tags: wpf

I am having a problem, or perhaps I am confused.

I have a laptop connected to an external monitor with a resolution 1680x1050. In the windows settings, it is recommended a sacale of 100% but for me it all too small, text in the internet browser, file explorer... and so on.

So I set in windows a scale of 125%, for me it is a good sacle. The problem is when I am designing the WPF windows, I have less space than the real space, I have 25% less space. So when I depploy the application, some users have a 1080p monitor, so they see a lot of empty space.

I am wondering if there is some way to adjust the size of the controls to the real space, no matter if the user set scale in windows or not.

I was  thinking if there is a way the application detect the sacale that user set in windows and then in the WPF, apply the opposite scale, for example, if the user has a 125% in windows, WPF should to reduce the sacale 25% (more or less, theory it would be a little more) until 100%.

Or perhaps there would be a better option.

In sumary, I would like for example design my application for example for 1080p, and no matter if the user sets scale or not in windows, I would like to the application in a proportion that fit to the view for a 1080p monitor with no scale. Supposing that the user has a 1080p monitor too, but with scale.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have tried to use an application manifest in my WPF Core project, and in the properties I have set it as resorce, I uncomment this code:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

It seems it should be to help, But in my case I still have the same behaviour, in my monitor with 125% of scale in windows, I have less space.